# Favorite filter Odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo

I know how to code python filters or groups for example:

```
<filter string="Current year" name="anneescolaire" domain="[('default_school_year','=',True),('period_school_year','=',False)]"/>
```

In the Odoo interface, I saw that it is possible to add a favorite filter. Is it possible to code a favorite filter?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, but it's not a filter as part of a search view. It's just a record of model `ir.filters`. So you have to create it per xml or csv file in your module/app.

For example:

```xml
<record id="filter_company_customers" model="ir.filters">
    <field name="name">My Companies</field>
    <field name="model_id">res.partner</field>
    <field name="user_id" eval="False"/>
    <field name="domain">[('is_company','=',True), ('customer', '=', True)]</field>
</record>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Besides you should create another question, because your original one was answered. And please add as much information as possible: What exactly is not working? What do you try to do with that filter? And so on...